# Setting first (nth?) dropdown entry as default using array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, svelte

I have a dropdown that works well with simple values, but I just tried using arrays as values and now the initial dropdown-entry is empty.

I have created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9a120e13aeac4049a50d2fca267df6cb?version=3.46.6) to illustrate the problem. As you can see I have also tried using `selected=...` to automatically select the first entry, but it doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of is to introduce another property to go back to simple values and then extract the array by filtering the original array, but it seems rather cumbersome. I wonder if there is another, more elegant, way that I'm missing.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Here the code example as suggested:

```
<script>
    const availableFilters = [
        { key: ['filterAll'], display: 'All Columns' },
        { key: ['name1', 'name2' ], display: 'Entry Names' },
        { key: ['ID1', 'ID2' ], display: 'Entry IDs' },
        { key: ['name1'], display: 'Entry 1 Name' },
        { key: ['ID1'], display: 'Entry 1 ID' },
        { key: ['name2'], display: 'Entry 2 Name' },
        { key: ['ID2'], display: 'Entry 2 ID' },
    ];
    
    const simpleAvailableFilters = [
        { key: 'filterAll', display: 'All Columns' },
        { key: 'name1', display: 'Entry 1 Name' },
        { key: 'ID1', display: 'Entry 1 ID' },
        { key: 'name2', display: 'Entry 2 Name' },
        { key: 'ID2', display: 'Entry 2 ID' },
    ];
    
    
    let currentFilter = { key: ['filterAll'], value: "", code: 0 };
    let simpleCurrentFilter = { key: 'filterAll', value: "", code: 0 };
</script>

Dropdown with array values: 
<select bind:value={currentFilter.key}>
    {#each availableFilters as filter, i}
        <option selected={i === 0 ? 'selected' : ''} value={filter.key}>{filter.display} - {i}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
<span>
    Selected key: {currentFilter.key}
</span>
<br/>
Simple Dropdown:
<select bind:value={simpleCurrentFilter.key}>
    {#each simpleAvailableFilters as filter, i}
        <option value={filter.key}>{filter.display} - {i}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
<span>
    Selected key: {simpleCurrentFilter.key}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```
let currentFilter = { key: ['filterAll'], value: "", code: 0 };
```

by

```
let currentFilter = availableFilters[0];
```

Even though the object has the exact same structure, it's still a different object that the one on the first position in the array. `{} === {} // false` The same applies to arrays.

```
['filterAll'] === ['filterAll'] // false
'filterAll' === 'filterAll' // true
```

`currentFilter` would have then this structure

```
{key: *bindedValue*, display: 'All Columns'}
```

If you want to extract the array you have to access the key when setting the initial value

```
let currentFilter = availableFilters[0].key;
```

and change the binding on the option

```
<select bind:value={currentFilter}>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/23129d2c7cc14f31ab2f2919e627c04a?version=3.46.6)
A Repl is great to have, but it would be better to include the code as well, in case the Repl might break...

Comment: Perfect, thank you once again for helping me here and on Discord! :) I guess I should have known this one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let currentFilter = availableFilters[0].key;
```

and you can remove `selected={i === 0 ? 'selected' : ''}` from the `option`.

See https://svelte.dev/tutorial/select-bindings